# How can I serializeArray for unchecked checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How can I [**modify this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dFktd/2/) so it can get values from checkboxes that aren't checked?

I want all checkboxes to have a value, if it hasn't been checked I want to get its value as `false`.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Check01" value="true" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Check02" value="true" checked="checked" />
```

Default behavior

```
$("form").serializeArray();
// [Check02 = true]
```

Expected behavior

```
$("form").serializeArray();
// [Check01 = false, Check02 = true]
```

Comment: This is a poor approach. You should have a collection of all available values in the server side (and eventually use it to autogenerate the checkboxes) and upon form submit intersect it with the submitted checked values to get the unchecked values.

Comment: @BalusC What if the checkboxes are used as switches and not a collection? Then a true/false value is required unless you want to do a bunch of checking for submitted values on the server side.

Comment: @mwieczorek: just use `false` as default?

Comment: Yes, but in strictly typed languages (or strict mode in PHP, which should *always* be on), that POST array/object would not include the key/value for the unchecked checkbox and would throw an exception if referenced. It's just another `if` or ternary statement to check if the key exists in the array or object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's probably easiest to just do it yourself:

```
 var serialized = $('input:checkbox').map(function() {
   return { name: this.name, value: this.checked ? this.value : "false" };
 });
```

If there are other inputs, then you could serialize the form, and then find the unchecked checkboxes with something like the above and append that result to the first array.

Comment: how do you append the value of the other inputs to this `serializedObj`

Comment: @Smith you'd do something like `serialized.push({name: "something", value: "whatever"});`

Comment: Slightly modified version of this that first uses serializeArray on a form (except filters out hidden elts), then adds in unchecked checkboxes to it:

`formDataJson = $('#' + formId + ' [type!="hidden"]').serializeArray();
//Jquery's serializeArray does not handle unchecked checkboxes, so need to do this to add them:
var unchecked_serialized_cb = $('#' + formId + '[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').map(function() { formDataJson.push({ name: this.name, value: this.checked ? this.value : "false" });`

Answer (score 16):

**`serializeArray` ignores the checkboxes which are not checked.** You can try something like this.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rgZgH/)**

```
    var serializedObj = {};
    $("form input:checkbox").each(function(){
        serializedObj[this.name] = this.checked;
    });
```

Comment: how do you append the value of the other inputs to this `serializedObj`

Comment: **serializeArray ignores the checkboxes which are not checked** this really needs to be highlighted

Comment: Though recognize that you have two options, to use true/false, or to use the value of the checkbox when checked and another value when not checked such as empty string or undefined.

Answer (score 4):

another option is to just look at the source code for serializeArray and remove (or modify) the call to filter.  I Just took that function and created a new one called serializeArrayAll like this:

```
$.fn.serializeArrayAll = function() {
  var rCRLF = /\r?\n/g;
  return this.map(function(){
      return this.elements ? jQuery.makeArray( this.elements ) : this;
  })
  /* this is what is excluding the unchecked checkboxes (and also other disabled options) 
      .filter(function(){
        return this.name && !this.disabled &&
            ( this.checked || rselectTextarea.test( this.nodeName ) ||
                rinput.test( this.type ) );
    })
   */
  .map(function( i, elem ){
      var val = jQuery( this ).val();

      return val == null ?
          null :
          jQuery.isArray( val ) ?
              jQuery.map( val, function( val, i ){
                  return { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( rCRLF, "\r\n" ) };
              }) :
          { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( rCRLF, "\r\n" ) };
  }).get();
};
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use this get unchecked values

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function () {
    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
var $radio = $('input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox]',this);
$.each($radio,function(){
    if(!o.hasOwnProperty(this.name)){
        o[this.name] = '';
    }
});
return o;
};
```

[code samples](http://codepen.io/tangolivesky/pen/bZxrkx)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I implemented a simple override of `$.serializeArray` which fixes the default serialization behaviour for checkboxes, and default behaviour is retained for all other types.

In the code below, missed checkboxes are injected into the original serialized array. Checkbox state is returned as `"true"` (instead of `"on"`) or `"false"` depending on if it is `checked` or not.

```
(function ($) {
    var _base_serializeArray = $.fn.serializeArray;
    $.fn.serializeArray = function () {
        var a = _base_serializeArray.apply(this);
        $.each(this.find("input"), function (i, e) {
            if (e.type == "checkbox") {
                e.checked 
                ? a[i].value = "true" 
                : a.splice(i, 0, { name: e.name, value: "false" })
            }
        });
        return a;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You could customize this to return `"on"/"off"` or `true/false`.

*Update: Fixed code based on bug found by @shyammakwana.me.*

Comment: Uh oh, this code is dangerously wrong! It assumes that base serializeArray result has EXACTLY PRECISELY the same order and contents as the order of find("input"). But if your form has textarea's or select's, you will end up corrupting your form values by assigning true/false to wrong fields!

Answer (score 2):

You can append unchecked checkbox data to `.serializeArray` result:

```
var formData = $("#mybaseelement").serializeArray();
$('#mybaseelement input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').each(function(i, e) {
    formData.push({name: e.getAttribute("name"), value: false});
});
```

This is the least invasive solution I can come up with.

Comment: I like this approach. No hidden fields, no extra code. Only negative is lose the order of items in the form data, but can live with it.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a hidden false value for every checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Check01" value="true" /><input name="Check01" type="hidden" value="false" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Check02" value="true" checked="checked" /><input name="Check02" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

You will only get "false" values for unchecked checkboxes and both "true" and "false" for checked checkboxes, so you can remove the duplicates like this:

```
var params = {};
$.each($('form').serializeArray(), function (index, value) {
    params[value.name] = params[value.name] ? params[value.name] || value.value : value.value;
});
console.log(params); // outputs: {"Check01":"false","Check02":"true"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the jQuery plugin [serializeJSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON), you can use the `data-unchecked-value` attribute to specify the value when unchecked:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Check01" value="true" data-unchecked-value="false" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Check02" value="true" data-unchecked-value="false" checked="checked" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$('input').serializeJSON({ parseBooleans: true });
// returns => { 'Check01' : false, 'Check02' : true }
```

Answer (score 1):

I made my own new solution based on the answers by @Pointy, @Ben, and the original jQuery code. The answer from @Pointy had odd behavior that returned contexts for checkboxes, this fixes that problem. The answer from @Ben was also not acting properly because it always returned `checkbox = on` even if it was unchecked.

```
$.fn.serializeArrayWithCheckboxes = function() {
var rCRLF = /\r?\n/g;
return this.map(function(){
    return this.elements ? jQuery.makeArray( this.elements ) : this;
})

    .map(function( i, elem ){
        var val = jQuery( this ).val();


        if (val == null) {
          return val == null
        //next 2 lines of code look if it is a checkbox and set the value to blank 
        //if it is unchecked
        } else if (this.type == "checkbox" && this.checked == false) {
          return { name: this.name, value: this.checked ? this.value : ""}
        //next lines are kept from default jQuery implementation and 
        //default to all checkboxes = on
        } else {
          return jQuery.isArray( val ) ?
                jQuery.map( val, function( val, i ){
                    return { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( rCRLF, "\r\n" ) };
                }) :
            { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( rCRLF, "\r\n" ) };
        }
    }).get();
};
```

Comment: `return val == null` will return `true` if value is null. Also, this.checked is checked in an `else if` which is entered only if `this.checked` is == false.

Answer (score 1):

[@SNag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335281/how-can-i-serializearray-for-unchecked-checkboxes#50022856) worker almost 99% just with little bit correction. 
Change below line

#### from :

```
$.each(this, function (i, e) {
```

#### to:

```
$.each(this.find('input'), function (i, e) {
```

*Explanation: As this was not working because `this` returned form element. So on form `.each` won't give us all input elements inside form. So I did this correction and it worked like charm.*

Comment: Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

## Yet Another SerializeArray()

This implementation is again based on jQuery's original code, but I needed it for some [Bootstrap's "switch" checkboxes](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) with two different values.

```
$.fn.serializeArrayWC = function() {
    var rCRLF = /\r?\n/g;
    return this.map(function(){
        return this.elements ? jQuery.makeArray( this.elements ) : this;
    })
    .map(function(i, elem){
        if (this.type == "checkbox") {
            // Bootstrap checkboxes with two different values.
            if (jQuery(this).hasClass("switched")) {
                // Always return value (either on-value or off-value).
                return { name: this.name, value: this.value };
            }
            // Normal checkboxes. Unchecked checkboxed are not returned.
            if (!this.checked) {
                // This will be removed by the !!f filter, below.
                return false;
            }
            // Return the value, or "on".
            return { name: this.name, value: this.value||"on" };
        }
        var val = jQuery(this).val();
        if (val == null) {
            return { name: elem.name, value: null };
        } else {
            return jQuery.isArray(val) ?
                jQuery.map( val, function( val, i ){
                    return { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( rCRLF, "\r\n" ) };
                }) :
            { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( rCRLF, "\r\n" ) };
        }
    })
    .filter(function(i, f){ return !!f; })
    .get();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fields = $("form").serializeArray();
$('form input[type=checkbox]').map(function() {
   if( !this.checked )
        {
                fields.push({ name: this.name, value: "off" });
        }
   });
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/26966851)