# Checkbox won't return checked value in jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have the following post request. It's sending all other fields successfully. However, whatever I try it simply does not pick up the check box. I've tested the id with a click event and alert and it's definitely referencing the checkbox ok.

```
$.post("http://" + window.location.host + "/exec_messages_send.php",
{
    receiver : $("#messages_receiver").val(),
    title : $("#messages_title").val(),
    body : $("#wysi_textarea_message_body").val(),
    urgent : $("#messages_urgent").checked
}
```

This is the html, rendered with php:

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"messages_urgent\"> Mark as <span class=\"label label-important\">Urgent</span>";
```

How do I get the value of the checkbox? I've already tried .val() and .attr('checked') and .checked and a few other methods...

Comment: `.checked` only works on regular javascript elements, not jQuery elements

Comment: Where is the value in check box ? If no value then you can get true or false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use -

`urgent : $("#messages_urgent")[0].checked`

Or

```
urgent : $("#messages_urgent").is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
$("#messages_urgent").is(':checked').val();
```

or you can directly like

```
$("#messages_urgent:checked").val();
```

and also give some value to checkbox

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"my_value\" id=\"messages_urgent\"> Mark as <span class=\"label label-important\">Urgent</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand your problem here, but maybe just use .prop():

```
urgent : $("#messages_urgent").prop('checked')
```

Comment: Or `urgent : $("#messages_urgent")[0].checked`

Comment: Or `urgent : $("#messages_urgent").get(0).checked`.  Using .prop() is just the jquery way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you want to serialize a form in some way. In your example you pick the fields in JS but unless you have need to change where the data is coming from dynamically, you'd get the same results far more easily by using the default behavior of submitting a form.

There doesn't seem to be a `name` attribute on the input element. Inputs without `name` are ignored by default, as are checkboxes with value `false`. But you can work around it with reading the checked-property as indicated in the other answers.

Normally serializing form also ignores checkboxes if they are not checked. Eg. [How can I serializeArray for unchecked checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335281/how-can-i-serializearray-for-unchecked-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0):

`$('#messages_urgent').is(':checked')` will do.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#messages_urgent").is(':checked'); // it returns true of false
```